# How to change Caption of an event in TcxScheduler?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2

How to change Caption of an event in TcxScheduler? I have tried the following code:

```
cxScheduler.SelectedEvents[i].Caption := 'X';
cxScheduler.Invalidate;
```

But Caption is obsolete until current event will be changed.

Also if you try to edit Caption by inplace editor and then cancel edit mode you'll see an obsolete value again.

The correct caption should be on the screen and on the related DataSet to save data.

Thanks a lot for the help!

P.S. Related DevExpress issue link: [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q415984)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DevExpress team solution:**

This behavior is caused by the fact that you changed the caption of the control event, but not the TcxSchedulerEvent item itself. I suggest you use the following code, instead:

```
if cxScheduler.SelectedEventCount > 0 then
    cxScheduler.SelectedEvents[0].Source.Caption := 'X';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use OnCustomDrawEvent, like:

```
procedure TForm1.cxScheduler1CustomDrawEvent(Sender: TObject;
  ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxSchedulerEventCellViewInfo;
  var ADone: Boolean);
begin
   AViewInfo.EventViewData.Caption := 'New Caption';
end;
```

And please - DevExpress has the one of the best support center I've ever seen - be advice to use it next time.

Comment: It's just an example, but it works. Here you can download working sample http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q392547

Comment: Thanks, but customization drawing and changing value are very different.

Comment: I have checked this code - and it doesn't work. Two issues exist on this case too.

Comment: JustMe, thanks for your answer - I'll use it for customization:)